# Subdivision surface shading problem in viewport only

Tags: 3d-view, subdivision-surface

I have a problem with visible shading lines in on my subdivision surface. It is only noticeable in solid viewport. There is no problem in the render view or rendered image. I have many other files with similar shapes and colors and are completely smooth in their subdivision surface. Never had a problem with this before. Have been using blender for several years. Below are some viewport settings that I typically use.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: check your clip distance. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr9qa.png

Comment: I'd guess that you're using a low-quality matcap, but if that's not the problem, I'd have to get a loser look. You can upload a blend file to BSE by using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thank you for responding! I do not have any matcaps configured. It is currently set to Studio lighting. I don't usually mess with these configurations often. Also the clip distance is okay.